# jQuery Animate Width Increase From middle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I am I just recently started to learn jQuery and while messing arround I started to buld a lightbox effect from scratch.This is my Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){


                $('<div id="overlay"></div>').css({opacity:'0' })
                        .animate({ opacity:'0.7'
                        },1500 )
                        .appendTo('body');
                $('<div id="container"></div>').css({
                                                    backgroundColor:'white',
                                                    opacity:'0'

                                                })
                                                .animate({
                                                        left:'470px',
                                                        top:'150px'
                                                },'fast')
                                                .animate({
                                                        opacity:'1'
                                                })
                                                .animate({
                                                         height:'+=255px'
                                                         },1000,'swing')
                                                .animate({
                                                        width:'+=350px'
                                                        },1000,'swing')
                                                .animate({
                                                        height:'+=50px'
                                                        },1000,'swing')

                                                .appendTo('body');
                $('<img/>').attr('src',$(this).attr('href')).appendTo('div#container');

                return false;
            }); 


        })
```

While trying to set the div to the center I created 2 variables :

```
 var left = ($(window).width() - $('div#container').width())/2
 var top = ($(window).height() - $('div#container').height())/2
```

The problem with these aproach is  that the initial width and height of the div is set to 50px so the coodinates center it with what they get the first time and when the rest of the animation runs the container isent centered anymore.

What first poped into my mind was trying to make the with and height of the container animate from the midle on both sides that way it will stay centered.

How can I achive this?I would like a solution the dosen't rely on external plugins except jQuery UI.Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is calculate your center based on the new width/height css values, and then translate the box based on the change of these coordinates, making it appear to stay centered. I don't have time to make a js fiddle, but you could add left and right values to your animation.

```
 var new_left = ($(window).width() - //final width value )/2;
 var new_top = ($(window).height() - //final height value )/2;
```

and then add an animation of something like:

```
  .animate({
            left:new_left,
            top:new_top
            }, //time interval , //method);
```

Comment: wow this worked better than I expected it to on the first try, thanks!